# Twig's "column" filter missing $index_key argument

Tags: twig

Twig 2.8's new `column` filter:

> Internally ... uses the PHP `array_column` function

but it does not support `array_column`'s `$index_key` argument,
 which is extremely useful for quickly converting arrays of objects into an array of `id => value` pairs.

Will this be supported in a future release?

Comment: Might be better raising that as an issue at https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues

Comment: already filed a [pull request](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/3094)

Comment: Is now [merged](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/pull/3094) - Should not be a problem in the (near) future anymore